# How to keep MPMoviePlayerController open after movie ended?

Tags: iphone, sdk, mpmovieplayercontroller

If I use MPMoviePlayerController to play video in my iPhone app, it opens, loads the movie, plays it and then closes. Is it possible to force it to stay open after the movie finishes, so that user can replay it using its controls, instead of using controls in parent view? Also, is it possible to start MPMoviePlayerController in the paused mode?

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of that is possible using the available API in the Pre-3.2 OS.  One thing you could do is take a scerenshot of the last frame and stick that behind the movie so when it's done playing, it looks like it's still there, then just stick a button on it to replay.  you could make an interface that looks/behaves similar to the standard movie player interface just for the play button if you need to.

Comment: Thanks. That's bad news, but at least I know the problem is in the SDK, not in me 8)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling over this now... There is a way to do this. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420564/how-to-stop-mpmovieplayerviewcontrollers-automatic-dismiss-on-movieplaybackdidf) question :)