# How to stop MPMoviePlayerViewController's automatic dismiss on moviePlaybackDidFinish?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

An MPMoviePlayerViewController which is presented modally through `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` automatically dismisses itself when it's content finishes playing.

I've tried to disable this, since I want to play other content afterwards. However, even if I register to the NSNotificationCenter with `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerVC.moviePlayer];` and set some other content, it still dismisses.

How can I stop MPMoviePlayerViewController from automatically dismissing itself?

**UPDATE:**

As a clarification, this question is *only* about removing the automatic dismissal and not about dealing with the disabled 'done' button. The selected answer reflects. This is by design, since we assume the developer adds their own means of dismissing the MPMoviePlayerViewController. However, **@bickster**'s answer deals with the 'done' button as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to [this blog article](http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/) I figured out that MPMoviePlayerViewController automatically registers itself to the NSNotificationCenter upon creation. You have to first remove this registration and it will stop dismissing itself automatically.

```
// Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerVC = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aVideoUrl]] autorelease];
// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:playerVC  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerVC.moviePlayer];
```

Comment: But, if i do that, "Done" button is not working anymore meaning I am not able to close the video player. Tested in iOS 7.

Comment: @MinSoe The question is merely about the automatic dismissal, assuming that the developer will install some way of dismissing the player itself. However, **@bickster**'s answer below should give you more mileage. He had the same issue.

Answer (score 20):

You can use this code to stop the viewcontroller from automatically dismissing and capture the event when the user clicks the "Done" button so you can dismiss the viewcontroller yourself.

Step 1. - alloc a MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[[NSURL alloc ]initWithString:[aURL];
```

Step 2. - Remove the default MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification observer and add your own

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:videoPlayer
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer.moviePlayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(videoFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer.moviePlayer];
```

Step 3. - Present viewcontroler

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayer];
```

Step 4. - Add videoFinish: method

```
-(void)videoFinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    int value = [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
    if (value == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {
        [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    }
}
```

Comment: Truly curious. Why add another, near-duplicate answer to a question that was answered almost a year ago?

Comment: It's not near duplicate.  The answer did not work for me.  The answer I provided works and is more complete.  Something must have changed since this question was answered.  I'm hoping my answer will save people the hours that I spent figuring out how it works today.  I hope my answer satisfies your curiosity.

Comment: It's just that the actual question is just about removing the actual dismissal, which is answered in the first line of code of your step 2. I don't really understand what the rest does, beyond adding the same functionality you're trying to remove.

Comment: This is a better answer because if you don't do this (at least in iOS 7) then there is no way for the user to dismiss the controller at all. With this approach you get "what you want" in that the controller appears and then stays around until the user explicitly tells it to go away.  If that's not what you want, well, then don't do it this way :)

Comment: This is the right answer - making the video player stay on the screen UNTIL the user explicitly presses "Done". The only thing I'd like, @bickster, is that you correct the last line in the 2nd snippet - you're missing a " object:nil];" I think :)

Comment: This does not work for me. What goes at the end of the second code snippet after MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification?

Comment: this is the perfect answer. Works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

when the mpmovieplayercontroller finishes playing a video and you recieve the notification in your method **movieFinishedCallback:** implemect

```
       [playerVC.movieplayer setContentURL:// set the url of the file you want to play here];

       [playerVC.moviePlayer play];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since "Done" button is not working anymore if I remove `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` from `NSNotificationCenter`, I change repeat mode to `MPMovieRepeatModeOne`.
Then, everything's working fine except the video is repeated.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerVC = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aVideoUrl]] autorelease];
[playerVC.moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeOne];
```