# Do NOT auto dismiss MPMoviePlayerViewController on finish?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, movies are automatically dismissed after they are finished playing. I would like for the controller only to be dismissed upon clicking the done button. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.postInfo.referenceText];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL] autorelease];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:controller];
```

Comment: It is a duplidate question. you can find answer [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420564/how-to-stop-mpmovieplayerviewcontrollers-automatic-dismiss-on-movieplaybackdidf/13420566#13420566

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else checking this out, this blog post has the solution: http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/