# MPMoviePlayerController display controls after the movie ends

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm displaying a short clip fullscreen, and at the end I would like NOT to dismiss the `MPMoviePlayerController`, as is the default behaviour, but to simple show the controls and allow the user to tap "Done" when they are ready to move on.

So far I managed to disable the auto-dismiss with the help of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19596598/362657 now I just need to show the controls.

I have the following:

```
-(void)videoFinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    int value = [[aNotification.userInfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];
    if (value == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) { // user tapped Done
        [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
    } else { // movie finished playing
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = aNotification.object;
        // do something to show the controls, but what?
    }
}
```

I tried setting the `controlStyle` to none and then back to fullscreen, but that still has no effect until user taps the screen. Is there any way to trigger the display of the movie controls programmatically?